# Running foundation build fails with an error: TypeError: stream.on is not a function

Tags: gulp, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6, npm-request

Working with a new client, their front-end guys send over their setup for the toolchain. They use macosx(Linux) and it works for them. In windows 10 pro, it fails to run the build routine as it should. I have tried for a few days to see what is needed to make it work in the final build step.

C:\Users\xxxxx\source\repos\xxxx-kentico-website\CMS\PatternLibrary>npm run build

```
> foundation-zurb-template@1.0.0 build C:\Users\xxxxx\source\repos\xxxx-kentico-website\CMS\PatternLibrary
> gulp build --production

[19:22:05] Failed to load external module @babel/register
[19:22:05] Requiring external module babel-register
[19:22:09] Using gulpfile ~\source\repos\xxxx-kentico-website\CMS\PatternLibrary\gulpfile.babel.js
[19:22:09] Starting 'build'...
[19:22:09] Starting 'clean'...
[19:22:09] Finished 'clean' after 66 ms
[19:22:09] Starting 'pages'...
[19:22:09] Starting 'sass'...
[19:22:09] Starting 'javascript'...
[19:22:09] Starting 'images'...
[19:22:09] Starting 'copy'...
[19:22:10] 'images' errored after 1.34 s
[19:22:10] **TypeError: stream.on is not a function**
    at Readable.wrap (C:\Users\xxxxx\source\repos\xxxx-kentico-website\CMS\PatternLibrary\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:817:10)
at wrap (C:\Users\xxxxx\source\repos\xxxx-kentico-website\CMS\PatternLibrary\node_modules\stream-combiner2\index.js:67:29)
at combine (C:\Users\xxxxx\source\repos\xxxx-kentico-website\CMS\PatternLibrary\node_modules\stream-combiner2\index.js:29:18)
at Function.module.exports.obj (C:\Users\xxxxx\source\repos\xxxx-kentico-website\CMS\PatternLibrary\node_modules\stream-combiner2\index.js:22:10)
at Imagemin.createStream (C:\Users\xxxxx\source\repos\xxxx-kentico-website\CMS\PatternLibrary\node_modules\imagemin\index.js:103:24)
at Imagemin.run (C:\Users\xxxxx\source\repos\xxxx-kentico-website\CMS\PatternLibrary\node_modules\imagemin\index.js:77:20)
at DestroyableTransform.through.obj.percent (C:\Users\xxxxx\source\repos\xxxx-kentico-website\CMS\PatternLibrary\node_modules\gulp-imagemin\index.js:56:12)
at DestroyableTransform._transform (C:\Users\xxxxx\source\repos\xxxx-kentico-website\CMS\PatternLibrary\node_modules\through2-concurrent\through2-concurrent.js:30:15)
at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (C:\Users\xxxxx\source\repos\xxxx-kentico-website\CMS\PatternLibrary\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:182:10)
at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (C:\Users\xxxxx\source\repos\xxxx-kentico-website\CMS\PatternLibrary\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:170:83)
at doWrite (C:\Users\xxxxx\source\repos\xxxx-kentico-website\CMS\PatternLibrary\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:406:64)
at writeOrBuffer (C:\Users\xxxxx\source\repos\xxxx-kentico-website\CMS\PatternLibrary\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:395:5)
at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (C:\Users\xxxxx\source\repos\xxxx-kentico-website\CMS\PatternLibrary\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:322:11)
at DestroyableTransform.ondata (C:\Users\xxxxx\source\repos\xxxx-kentico-website\CMS\PatternLibrary\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:612:20)
at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:180:13)
at DestroyableTransform.emit (domain.js:439:23)
[19:22:10] 'build' errored after 1.42 s
[19:22:10] The following tasks did not complete: pages, sass, javascript, copy
[19:22:10] Did you forget to signal async completion?
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! foundation-zurb-template@1.0.0 build: `gulp build --production`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the foundation-zurb-template@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04-10T23_22_10_624Z-debug.log
```

Version(s) used:

```
Foundation CLI version 2.2.5
Node v9.10.1
Gulp CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp Local version 4.0.0-alpha.3
Ruby Sass 3.5.6
Windows 10 Pro Version 10.0.16299.309
Python 2.7.9 (client requirement)
NPM 5.6.0
GIT version 2.16.2.windows.1
```

Client Package json:

```
{
  "name": "foundation-zurb-template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Official ZURB Template for Foundation for Sites.",
  "main": "gulpfile.babel.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gulp",
    "build": "gulp build --production"
  },
  "author": "ZURB <foundation@zurb.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "access-sniff": "^3.1.0",
    "foundation-sites": "~6.4.1",
    "imagemin-jpegtran": "^5.0.2",
    "jquery": ">=3.0.0",
    "motion-ui": "~1.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.8.3",
    "what-input": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.10.0",
    "colors": "^1.1.2",
    "gulp": "github:gulpjs/gulp#4.0",
    "gulp-accessibility": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^3.3.1",
    "gulp-cli": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-color": "0.0.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.5.2",
    "gulp-extname": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-htmlhint": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.4.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-uncss": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "gulp-wcag-accessibility": "0.0.1",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "^4.2.2",
    "js-yaml": "^3.4.6",
    "panini": "^1.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.4.3",
    "style-sherpa": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-named": "^1.1.0",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-stream": "^3.2.0",
    "yargs": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/zurb/foundation-zurb-template.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues",
    "email": "foundation@zurb.com"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015"
    ]
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try switching to Node.js 8 using nvm. The issue is in readable-stream, not foundation-sites.

Please use the `zurb-foundation` tags instead of the `foundation` tag next zime.

And try to link to the issue that you posted on GitHub. Crossposting without linking is not the best solution in general.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you no longer need help for this, but anyway ..

I had the same issue few days ago, and fixed it changing:

`"gulp": "github:gulpjs/gulp#4.0",` for `"gulp": "^4.0.0",` (make sure to run npm install after that)

and switching to `Node v 7.10.1` (with nvm as Daniel said)